# getBoundingClientRect() is returning 0's, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an `<img>` element move to another element (`<a>`) by first getting the position with `getBoundingClientRect()` and then to use those values to set the `<img>` element position on mouseover. But when I check the logs it's just spitting 0's. What am I doing wrong / overlooking?

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');
var imgPreviewEle = document.getElementById('artistPreview');

clickers.forEach(function(clicker) {
    clicker.addEventListener('mouseover', function hover() {
        var elem = clicker.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(elem);
        imgPreviewEle.style.display = "block";
        imgPreviewEle.style.left = elem.left + 300 + 'px';
        imgPreviewEle.style.top = elem.top - 300 + 'px';
    });
});

clickers.forEach(function(clicker) {
    clicker.addEventListener('mouseleave', function hover() {
        var elem = clicker.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(elem);
        imgPreviewEle.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

```css
.clicker {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(18.4, 31, 31, .5);
}
#artistPreview {
    z-index: 1010; 
    position: fixed; 
    clip: rect(290px, 600px, 620px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<img id="artistPreview" src="" />
<div class="container">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li onMouseOver="show('A')" onMouseOut="hide('A')">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-weight: 600;">A</a>
            <ul id="A">
                <a class="clicker" href="javascript:void(0)">ABBA</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your HTML codes as well

Comment: Why do you have HTML onMouseOver and onMouseOut for a function that is not defined?

Comment: It's defined i just didn't include it here. It's a simple function that hides or shows an element by id as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes and left some comments. Let me know if you need more info:

```js
var clickers = document.querySelectorAll('.clicker');
var imgPreviewEle = document.getElementById('artistPreview');

// Hide the image from the start
imgPreviewEle.style.display = "none";

clickers.forEach(function(clicker) {
  clicker.addEventListener('mouseover', function hover() {
    var elem = clicker.getBoundingClientRect();
    imgPreviewEle.style.display = "block";
    
    // Make sure the image appears nearby
    // Looks like the -300px you had here pushed the image off screen.
    imgPreviewEle.style.left = (elem.left + elem.width) + 'px';
    imgPreviewEle.style.top = (elem.top + elem.height) + 'px';
    
    console.log(elem);

});
});

clickers.forEach(function(clicker) {
  clicker.addEventListener('mouseleave', function hover() {
    var elem = clicker.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(elem);
    imgPreviewEle.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.clicker {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(18.4, 31, 31, .5);
}

#artistPreview {
  z-index: 1010;
  position: fixed;
  /* The image should not cover the mouseover field. */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<! The image will need an SRC to be visible. >
<img id="artistPreview" src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80" />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <! Removed some event handler refs that did not have definitions in code. >
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-weight: 600;">A</a>
      <ul id="A">
        <a class="clicker" href="javascript:void(0)">ABBA</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. While everything you said is true, the code you had issues with is defined i just didnt include it because it wasnt relevant and didnt want to post more code than necessary. for instance, the img doesnt need a source in order for this.getBoundingClientRect(); to give values of the clicker element, which is where the origin of the problem lies.

Comment: No worries! I just wanted to make sure to point out all of my changes. I didn't want you to think that  was what caused the issue.